# How to handle sqlite extension as a property in object

Tags: javascript, angular, sqlite, typescript, trim

I am building an app with Ionic Native. I have a sql statement returns some data and U am using trim function in that statement. (I can post the sql statement if it is required.)

My problem is that I am having trim function in Object property so I cannot use it to display in my content.

Here the result in chrome://inspect.

```html
Object {trim(iv.CODE): "0117093", trim(iv.NAME): " PEPPER 12X200GR"
```

I want to display it in the content with Angular like:
 {{ someData.trim(iv.CODE) }}

But it returns error of course, it says "CODE" not defined. How can I overcome this problem?

Edit : 
If i use it like {{ someData.trim(someData.CODE) }} then, it returns the error undefined is not a function

The function below is the way how i retrieve my array from sqlite.

```js
db.retrieve("select distinct trim(iv.CODE),trim(iv.NAME), iv.P4,iv.UNIT,iv.UNIT2,iv.UNIT3, iv.UNIT2MULT,iv.UNIT3MULT,iv.VAT_O,iv.ACCODE3,iv.P4_VAT, ZT.NAME from invcards iv join ZCATINVTREE zi on zi.INVCODE=iv.CODE join ZCATTREE zt on zt.CODE=zi.CATCODE  where 1=1 and iv.EXCODE3='OK' and zi.CATCODE like '%"+this.categoryID+"%' and iv.VAT_O> 0 and iv.P4>0").then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.res = result;
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < this.res.rows.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.res.rows.item(i));
        this.itemList.push(this.res.rows.item(i));
      }
      this.initializeItems();
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
```

Comment: What does this.res.rows.item(i) prints?

Comment: It prints the current item of the array

Comment: I mean what is the item? Is it that object?

Comment: Yeah it is a object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach each object's key and get value like this:

```
var obj = {'trim(iv.CODE)': "0117093", 'trim(iv.NAME)': " PEPPER 12X200GR"}
for(var j in obj){
    var key = j;
    var val = obj[j];
    console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: Can you please check the question again with the method i've just added.

Comment: `var tempN = 'trim(iv.NAME)';
console.log(this.res.rows.item(i).tempN);
`
I tried to reach item in this way but it returns undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. I was using "." notation to reach the item but when i used :

this.res.rows.item(i)[temp] . I succeeded to reach the property.